# How to put a table below a ggplot and colour the rows by the same grouping factor as the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'd like to put a table below my plot, but I'd like the colour of the rows to match the colour of the groups in the plot (using 'predictor' as the common grouping factor for colours). Could anyone help me work out how to colour the table rows by group? Here's an example:

```
d <- data.frame(USArrests)
d$predictor <- factor(c(rep(c(1, 2), times = 25)))

library(dplyr)
label <- d %>% 
  group_by(predictor) %>%
  filter(Assault == max(Assault))

table <- data.frame(label$predictor)
table$measure1 <- c(1.45, 5.67)
table$measure2 <- c(4.55, 6.11)
table.p <- ggtexttable(table, rows = NULL,
                        theme = ttheme("mOrange"))

library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(d, aes(x=UrbanPop, y=Assault, fill=predictor)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(width = 0, preserve = "single"), width = 5) +
  geom_text(data = label, aes(label = UrbanPop), vjust = -0.5)

ggarrange(a, table.p,
          ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
          heights = c(1, 0.4))
```

Comment: imo you should have the colors selected yourself and use them both on table and on plot by appropriate using options (not using r, so i'll leave it here)

Comment: @NikosM. Thanks, though do you know how to assign colours by row (or by value in the first column) in the table?

Comment: I dont use r, but I suppose there should be options that cpntrol the colors and can be assigned by user programmaticaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
table.p <- ggtexttable(table, rows = NULL,
                       theme = ttheme(colnames.style = colnames_style(color = "Black", fill = "grey"),
                                      tbody.style = tbody_style(color = "black", fill = as.factor(d$predictor))))

library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(d, aes(x=UrbanPop, y=Assault, fill=predictor)) +
  geom_col(position=position_dodge(width = 0, preserve = "single"), width = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=as.factor(d$predictor))+
  geom_text(data = label, aes(label = UrbanPop), vjust = -0.5)

ggarrange(a, table.p,
          ncol = 1, nrow = 2,
          heights = c(1, 0.4))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do both as an automatic colour scale so they can take more predictors?

Comment: you can set, fill = as.factor(d$predictor) in both places. I'll update in my answer soon.